# how to get the value of the address in lightning-input-address

Tags: lightning-web-components

So I have this code.

```
 <lightning-input-address
            name='txtBillingAddress'
            address-label="Billing Address"
            street-label="Street"
            city-label="City"
            country-label="Country"
            province-label="Province"
            postal-code-label="PostalCode"
            required
            field-level-help="Help Text for inputAddress field"
            onchange={genericInputChange}
            ></lightning-input-address>
```

and on the generic input change i tried logging it as i am changing the values:

```
 genericInputChange(event){
        let val = event.target.value;
        console.log('val' , val);
        console.log('targetname' , event.target.name);
  }
```

I am having the correct event.target.name which is the txtBillingAddress
but I am having some issue when it comes to getting the value of the address... I have done searching and found the solution for the lightning-component , but I can't seem to find any solution for lightning web components

Comment: what is your exact issue here? Can you please clear it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you check the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-address/documentation), you will find the custom event:

[image]

So, you need to get these directly on `target` as shown below:

```
genericInputChange(event){
    console.log('Street => ' , event.target.street);
    console.log('City => ' , event.target.city);
    console.log('Province => ' , event.target.province);
    console.log('Country => ' , event.target.country);
    console.log('postal Code => ' , event.target.postalCode);
}
```

You can check this [playground link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/1ceEvuBwO/1/edit)

Comment: Thanks so much for this :( been searching for a day already . Thank you so much!